# MVC3 Layout - Repeating Sections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

I would like to divide my layout page's main body into two sections: the actual body and a sidebar. That sidebar can contain 0, 1 or more `<div>` elements which will group controls or data together that I define statically in my view. In order not to repeat this div structure on every view, I would like to split this off into a section on my layout page. However, as a section cannot be defined more than once on a view, I cannot repeat them.

I could statically define a number of sidebar sections as follows, but this seems to be a dirty way to go about it:

```
<div id="sidebar1">
    @RenderSection("Sidebar1", false))
</div>
<div id="sidebar2">
    @RenderSection("Sidebar2", false))
</div>
```

Is there any way to dynamically define this type of layout?

I have seen a few mentions of Templated Razor Delegates which can be used as a function to encapsulate a parameter in a div block:

```
@{ 
    Func<dynamic, object> div = @<div class="block">@item</div>;
}
@div("Block 1")
@div("Block 2")
```

But these only seem to accept text which is not what I'm lookin for and they aren't inherited by a View when defined on the Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Templated Razor Delegates' is not restricted to accept only 'string'. You can define the delegate as:

In view:

```
@model IEnumerable<SidebarViewModel>

@{ 
    Func<SidebarViewModel, object> div = @<div class="block">@item.Name</div>;
}

@foreach (var block in Model)
{ 
    @div(block)
}
```

You will get full intellisense support in the delegate.

Sample ViewModel:

```
public class SidebarViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work very well for any fully dynamic blocks I want to add. Ultimately I decided instead to define several optional sections since the content I want to place in them is statically defined on each page rather than generated dynamically. This will work very well if I run into situations where I need to add more dynamic elements or ViewModels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you require more section to address this problem, instead what you can do is when you render sidebar section, you may just want to render the view(which will handle your multiple div logic dynamically) something like this

```
@section Sidebar
{
    @{Html.RenderAction("actiontorendermultipledivs", "Fromthiscontroller");}
}
```